# trying to find a logic error in a array narrowed it down but im unsure to as what it is any ideas?

Tags: java

as in title i seemly cannot find the logic error in this array, ive narrowed in down to a certain area but im still unsure as to what the problem is.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] num = { 7, 2, 6, 4, 12, 6, 1, 8, 49, 3 };
   int lowest = num[0];
   int highest = num[0];
   for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      if (num[i] < lowest) {
         lowest = num[i];
      } else {
         highest = num[i];
      }
   }
```

i think the error is somwhere in here but i could be wrong

```
 for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
      if (num[i] < lowest) {
         lowest = num[i];
      }
```

Comment: Hi Hamburger! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your question to clarify what exactly you're trying to do and what exactly is currently happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] num = { 7, 2, 6, 4, 12, 6, 1, 8, 49, 3 };
int lowest = num[0];
int highest = num[0];

// already used [0] so start at [1] 
for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
   if (num[i] < lowest) {
         lowest = num[i];
   } 
   // also need two comparisons and not being lowest does not mean it is the highest
   if (num[i] > highest) {
          highest = num[i];
  }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must nest another if statement inside the else because just because the number is not the lowest does not mean that it is the highest. So you must check if num[i] is higher than "highest".

```
for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
      if (num[i] < lowest) {
          lowest = num[i];
      } 
      else{
          if(num[i] > highest){
              highest = num[i]
          }
      }

   }
```